# How would I destroy_all or delete_all records except one in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm using "acts_as_tree" plugin for my user messaging thread feature on my website. I have a method that makes deleting selected messages possible. The messages don't actually get deleted. Their sender_status or recipient_status columns get set to 1 depending on what user is the sender or recipient of the message.

Anyway if both users have those status's set to one then that last line makes sure the message  row is completely moved from the database. Now this is fine as long as it's not the parent message being deleted. If the parent message deleted then the children that haven't been selected for deletion won't be accessible anymore.

Here is the method:

```
        def delete_all_users_selected_messages(message_ids, user_id, parent_id)
          Message.where(:id => message_ids, :sender_id => user_id).update_all(:sender_status => 1)
          Message.where(:id => message_ids, :recipient_id => user_id).update_all(:recipient_status => 1)
          Message.delete_all(:sender_status => 1, :recipient_status => 1, :parent_id => parent_id).where("id != ?", parent_id)
        end
```

It's quite obvious what I'm trying to do. I need to have the parent ignored. So where the primary key is equal to the parent_id means that row is a parent (normally the parent_id is nil but I needed it set to the primary keys value for some other reason, long story and not important). Anyway is there an SQL statement I can add on to the end of the last line in tat method? To make sure it only deletes messages where the id of the row is not equal to the parent_id?

I can arrange for the parent_id row to never be permitted for deletion unless the actual thread (MessageThreads table that references the messages tables conversations) is deleted.

Any way how can I make it so this parent row is ignored when that delete_all method is run?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in the end.

```
Message.where('id != ? AND parent_id = ?', parent_id, parent_id).where(:sender_status => 1, :recipient_status => 1).delete_all
```

Basically returns all messages of that particular conversation except the one where id == parent_id. Whenever id == parent_id this means it's a parent message.

Answer (score 30):

Nowadays in Rails 4, you can do:

```
Model.where.not(attr: "something").delete_all
```

and

```
Model.where.not(attr: "something").destroy_all
```

And don't forget about difference:

- destroy_all: The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their `destroy` method. Instantiates all the records and destroys them one at a time, so with a large dataset, this could be slow
- delete_all: All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their `destroy` method. Callbacks are not called.

Comment: Should be noted that callbacks are not fired on `delete_all` so if you have dependencies you're expecting to be deleted as well, they won't be. Use `destroy_all` instead for that need.

Comment: This should probably be the answer. Assuming update to destroy_all.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use association from the parent record, something like this?

```
Message.where(:id => parent_id).first
  .children.where(:sender_status => 1, :recipient_status => 1)
  .delete_all
```

Comment: Got undefined method children so I tried Message.where(:id => parent_id).first.children.delete_all(:sender_status => 1, :recipient_status => 1) .. then got wrong number of arguments 1 for 0

Comment: Yes sorry I missed `first`. Could you separate this chain to multiple line statements so we can find where the error occurs? For example get the parent record first, then call `children....`.

Comment: Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`id` = 343 LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)   this is the error from rails console

Comment: I ran this Message.where(:id => 343).first.children.delete_all(:sender_status => 1, :recipient_status => 1)

Comment: It still deletes the parent message if selected

Comment: Your way would work fine if parent_id for message was set to nil. Then parent message wouldn't come up as a child but in this situation parent_id of parent message is set to it's id.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a slightly different approach and have the model that has the `has_many` relationship have `:dependent => destroy` with it, e.g.
`User has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy`
That way you don't get the 'dangling orphan record' issue you describe.

I would try and approach it this way rather than thinking 'all records except'.
I don't know if there is something I am not addressing but this is what comes to find for the issue described.